# Convert text from uppercase and mixed to capitalize inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

In a WordPress page, inside a div, I want to convert text from uppercase and mixed to capitalize. Data are collected by a form where users use lowercase, uppercase and mixed.

CSS is not a solution because in 2017 CSS is not able to convert uppercase to capitalize.

I'm a beginner in JS and jQuery, please be patient.

**My script & my div:**

```js
<script>
jQuery.fn.capitalise = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            text = $this.text(),
            split = text.split(" "),
            res = [],
            i,
            len,
            component;
        for (i = 0, len = split.length; i < len; i++) {
            component = split[i];
            res.push(component.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase());
            res.push(component.substring(1).toLowerCase());
            res.push(" "); // put space back in
        }
        $this.text(res.join(""));
    });
};


$(".domecap").capitalise();
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="domecap">ADDRESS: STR. mihai BRAVU, nUmBER 196</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem? Your solution seems to be working, just remove the '<script>' and '</script>' from the JS section of the snippet

Comment: I'm inside a WordPress page, if I remove <script></script> the code is displayed as text on the published page, insted to execute.
On jsfiddle my code working, on my WordPress page not(and on console no error) :(

Comment: Where is the script located on your wordpress page? At the bottom or the top of the file? You could try putting the $(".domecap").capitalise(); line inside of a document ready function?

Comment: My script are on the top of the page(1st).  You say: "...putting the $(".domecap").capitalise(); line inside of a document ready function" -> I do not know how to do that(I specified I'm a beginner).

Comment: Try putting the script at the bottom of the page, after the html

Comment: OMG - This do the trick! Well as all tutorials(like w3school, etc) tell us to put script on top of the page.
Can you explain me why at bottom of the page, after html made to work?
Thanks!

Comment: It is because you are referencing the 'domecap' element before that part of the page has loaded. I've added an answer showing how you can put the script at the top of the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try arranging your html file in the following order, as well as putting the line `$(".domecap").capitalise();` inside a `$(document).ready()` function:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  jQuery.fn.capitalise = function() {
      return this.each(function() {
          var $this = $(this),
              text = $this.text(),
              split = text.split(" "),
              res = [],
              i,
              len,
              component;
          for (i = 0, len = split.length; i < len; i++) {
              component = split[i];
              res.push(component.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase());
              res.push(component.substring(1).toLowerCase());
              res.push(" "); // put space back in
          }
          $this.text(res.join(""));
      });
  };


  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".domecap").capitalise();
  });
</script>

<div class="domecap">ADDRESS: STR. mihai BRAVU, nUmBER 196</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! For other users: Please read last comment of first post made by @BlueBoy to understand why my code doesn't works on top of the page as <script></script>.

Answer (score 0):

try using this simple jQuery statement instead:

```
$(".domecap").text($(".domecap").text().toUpperCase());
```

this will get the text inside your div, convert it into uppercase and then apply onto the specified div.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use jquery to do this. Why not CSS and javascript can do? Like this:

```js
var str = document.getElementById('domecap');
var res = str.textContent.toLowerCase();
str.innerHTML = res;
```

```css
#domecap {
  text-transform: capitalize
}
```

```html
<div class="domecap" id="domecap">ADDRESS: STR. mihai BRAVU, nUmBER 196</div>
```